# Función recursiva devuelve undefined

Tags: javascript

Verán tengo la siguiente situación que me parece muy curiosa, soy relativamente nuevo en JS y estaba haciendo una práctica donde tengo tengo una lista de elementos que se renderizan en la página basados en una colección de Firebase, cada elemento de estos tiene un botón que copia un link el cual está contenido en un dataset del mismo, ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<button data-url="http://www.loquesea.com">
  <div>
    <svg...>
      <path ... />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <p>Copiar</p>
</button>
```

Como ven a razón de tener el botón visualmente de esta manera, este está conformado por varios elementos.

En un JS escucho por el evento click de cada uno de esos botones a fin de ejecutar una función que copiará ese link contenido en data-url de cada elemento.

El asunto está en que según lo que yo planeaba al hacer click en la función que escucha el evento, simplemente iba a tomar el target y leer el dataset, pero con la configuración de botón que tengo al hacer click, el target puede ser el button mismo, la etiqueta p, la etiqueta path, la etiqueta svg o bien el div que contiene el svg, por lo que decidí crear una función que tomara el target y evaluara si el mismo target era un button o en caso de ser alguno de sus elementos hijos fuese escalando hasta llegar al button y retornarlo para poder leer su dataset.

Probé primero con una función recursiva que según yo era lo mejor, pero resulta que a la hora de retornar si el target no es el button o la etiqueta p entonces lo que retorna es undefined, por lo que terminé implementando la función con un while y ya con eso funciona de maravilla.

```html
function obtenerPadreRecursivo(tagDeseado, elemento) {
  if(elemento.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagDeseado.toLowerCase()) {
    return elemento;
  }else if(elemento.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagDeseado.toLowerCase()) {
    return elemento.parentNode;
  }else{
    obtenerPadreRecursivo(tagDeseado, elemento.parentNode);
  }
}

function obtenerPadre(tagDeseado, elemento) {
  while(true) {
    if(elemento.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagDeseado.toLowerCase()) {
      return elemento;
    }else if(elemento.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagDeseado.toLowerCase()) {
      return elemento.parentNode;
    }else{
      elemento = elemento.parentNode;
    }
  }
}

function copiarLink(e) {
  //Prueba de las funciones
  console.log(obtenerPadreRecursivo('button', e.target));
  //Salida: undefined
  
  console.log(obtenerPadre('button', e.target));
  //Salida: <button data-url="...
}
```

Pero mi duda es ¿Porqué la función recursiva termina por devolver undefined? la verdad no terminé de entender que estaba sucediendo, agradezco si alguno me puede iluminar con su conocimiento.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas una función recursiva para obtener el botón, sin importar qué elemento fue el que disparó el evento:

- Si se trata de una función "no [flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)", en `this` vas a obtener el elemento asignado al evento, es decir, directamente el botón
- Si por alguna razón todavía necesitas el evento, entonces [`e.target.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) buscará el selector en los elementos ascendentes.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const buttonClick = function(e) {
    // Tanto this como e.target.closest('button') devuelven lo mismo
    console.log(this, e.target.closest('button'));
};

buttons.forEach(button => {
    // Dentro de la función buttonClick, this hará referencia al botón
    button.addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
});
```

```html
<button data-url="http://www.loquesea.com">
  <div>
    <svg...>
      <path ... />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <p>Copiar</p>
</button>
<button data-url="https://www.google.com">
  <div>
    <svg...>
      <path ... />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <p>Copiar</p>
</button>
```

Respecto a tu duda:

> ¿Porqué la función recursiva termina por devolver undefined? la verdad no terminé de entender que estaba sucediendo

En el último `else` de la función no estás devolviendo el valor, simplemente ejecutas recursividad; debería ir un `return` al inicio de esa línea. Y lo mismo pasa con la función `obtenerPadre()`, en lugar de asignar un valor a elemento, deberías devolverlo.

```
function obtenerPadreRecursivo(tagDeseado, elemento) {
  if(elemento.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagDeseado.toLowerCase()) {
    return elemento;
  }else if(elemento.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagDeseado.toLowerCase()) {
    return elemento.parentNode;
  }else{
    /* Aquí falta un return */
    obtenerPadreRecursivo(tagDeseado, elemento.parentNode);
  }
}
```

Comment: Excelente, probé ambas soluciones y funcionan a la perfección, muchas gracias.